# Build and Debug using ios 8.4 SDK in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 6.4 doesn't allow to debug on iOS 9 devices so i installed xcode 7 but it doesn't have iOS sdk 8.4 installed. Since I have a xcode 6.4 installation, i copied the

> **iPhoneOS8.4.sdk** to the /Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs folder

and copied the

> **iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk** to /Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs.

However the iOS 8.4 sdk does not appear in the base sdk options list.

Comment: isnt it easier to just build it in Xcode 6.4 then?

Comment: No i want to build using ios sdk 8.4 and debug on a ios 9 device. I cannot do it with Xcode 6.4 as Xcode cannot debug on ios 9 devices

Comment: Why is the app called `Xcode 3.app`?

Comment: i have Xcode 2 other Xcode's installed

Comment: I had the same problem. It's weird but there is an alias file in the `.../SDKs` directory, in my case, called iPhoneOS9.1.sdk. I deleted it, and the problem solved.

Comment: FYI, I am using Xcode 7.1.1. It seems that Xcode can automatically recognize the .sdk file (folder) in the `.../SDKs` directory. So the file name is irrelative. Don't forget to restart Xcode. Now I can using both 9.1 and 7.1 SDKs. It is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one work around for this situation. I used to do this in my routine work as below:

- Open your project in Xcode 6.4 (You can see iOS 9 device debugging is disabled)
- Now just open Xcode 7 (without any project opened from it) such that it looks active in "Dock Tray".

By doing above two steps, Xcode 6.4 will now enable to debug with iOS 9 devices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did what you said, but i get the same error message. iphone may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.

Comment: Okay, quit all Xcode apps.
- Open your proj in Xcode 6.4
- Then just open Xcode 7. Make sure when you open Xcode 7 it will open current active project again in Xcode. If so then close it. Your project must be active with Xcode 6.4 only.
- Connect your iOS 9 device.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to copying the `iPhoneOS8.4.sdk` folder you need to edit

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist

and set `MinimumSDKVersion` to `8.4` and restart Xcode. Then Xcode will find and list the older SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You were copying an iPhoneOS8.4.sdk which is a relative symlink to iPhoneOS.sdk in that same folder in xcode6. So you ended up with two symlinks (..8.4, ..9.1) pointing to xcode7’s iPhoneOS.sdk (which is iOS 9.1)

Remove any changes you made.

You got two options. The first is the preferred one, as xcode7 updates will delete your 8.4 SDK in the future.

1. create a symlink called iPhoneOS8.4.sdk in the xcode7-folder. Let it point to your xcode6 iPhoneOS.sdk (which is iOS 8.4)

   Use this command from your xcode7 sdk directory

   ```
       ln -s <your xcode6 path>/iPhoneOS.sdk iPhoneOS8.4sdk
   ```
2. copy the xcode6 iPhoneOS.sdk folder to the xcode7 location. Do not overwrite iPhoneOS.sdk (which is xcode7's iOS 9). Rename it to iPhone8.4sdk instead